# where in ELF file i can see the mangled names in c++

Tags: c++

I have read about name mangling and ELF file formats of object file. I would like to know which section/segment of ELF exactly, the mangled names are stored? .text or symbol table?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf at page 1-8. The symbol table (`.symtab` section) will contain all the symbols which is basically an address and a name which is an offset into the `.strtab` section. You can find the exact structures in that ELF_Format.pdf. Also take a look at this question for some of the differences between the sections: [String table in ELF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289843/string-table-in-elf)

A nice tool to play around with the elf format is `readelf`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf . I know that an executable of it is distributed with MinGW